# Kubernetes pod lifecyle notification for CronJob

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to get invoke some API for notification when a CronJob starts and completes.

I can have a initcontainer that invokes the API to inform that the Job got started. But, Is there any way to invoke the API just before the pod dies. I dont want this logic in the CronJob main container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kubernetes provides an API which supports `watch`, so you are immediately notified when changes of the kubernetes state happens.

This way you can listen for creation/completion/deletion of `Job` objects.

You can use the API from inside and outside the Kubernetes cluster, as long as the API server is reachable.

Comment: I am looking for watch for CronJob for each run. Can we achieve this using watch? How can i write a watch for the future Job?

Comment: You can watch all resources or a subset. So you can watch for all (even future) CronJob and Job objects. Basically you would watch <kube master>/apis/batch/v1/namespaces/<yournamespace>/jobs